# pandas to_datetime converts non-zero padded month and day into datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I am using `pd.to_datetime` to convert strings into `datetime`;

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'id':['DD-83']})
pd.to_datetime(df['id'].str.replace(r'\D+', ''), errors='coerce', format='%d%m')
```

`%d%m` defines zero-padded day and month, but the code still converts the above string into

```
0   1900-03-08
Name: id, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I am wondering how to avoid it being converted into datetime (e.g. convert to `NaT` in this case), if the month and day in a string are not 0-padded. So

```
 DD0306 
 DD0706
 DD-83
```

will convert to

```
 1900-06-03
 1900-06-07
 NaT
```

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45595943/how-to-require-a-timestamp-to-be-zero-padded-during-validation-in-python

Comment: I suggest to have `df['id'].str.replace(r'\D+', '-')` and then `format='%d-%m'`, so that there is a clear distinction. It returns `NaT` for `-83`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look for `-` and only pass strings without `-`.

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'id':['DD-83', 'DD0706', 'DD0306']})
```

Code:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['id'].loc[~df['id'].str.contains('-')].str.replace(r'\D+', ''), errors='coerce', format='%d%m')
```

Output:

```
       id   date
0   DD-83   NaT
1   DD0706  1900-06-07
2   DD0306  1900-06-03
```

Comment: but other valid strings like `DD0306`, `DD0706` also converted into `NaT`

Comment: I tried the code with `df = pd.DataFrame(data={'id':['DD-83']})`, `to_datetime(to_datetime(
            df['id'].loc[
                ~df['id'].str.contains('-')].str.replace(r'\D+', ''),
            errors='coerce', format='%d%m'), errors='coerce', format='%d-%m', infer_datetime_format=True)` but returned an empty Series rather than `NaT`

Comment: @daiyue, see the full edited answer. I have attached the setup as well.